# Trigger chef continuous deployment after new build is available

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, chef-infra, continuous-deployment

I am new to chef and I have tried every possible search word on Google but I cannot find a single doc/blog on how to trigger continuous deployment using chef.
Chef-server and chef-client are all setup; but I cannot figure out how to trigger deployment. How to make chef-client to run specific steps/cookbooks once a new build is available.

The use-case is very simple:
I have teamcity as my continuous integration tool, as soon as a merge happens on a branch, teamcity creates the archive and uploads it to a central repo of builds.
Now I want to use chef to download these build from central repo, stop the previous running build and deploy the new build. But how to trigger chef-clients to download new build and how to trigger specific cookbook for this use-case handling. (I don't want to run system provisioning cookbooks to run everytime a deployment is triggered)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a special "deploy" resource that is sadly misunderstood. See: https://docs.getchef.com/resource_deploy.html. This underlying resource is leveraged by other cookbooks such as "artifact" mentioned below and more complex cookbook such as the "application_*"

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [deploy artifact cookbook](https://github.com/riotgames/artifact-cookbook).  You would only need to write a wrapper around it to handle any special cases for your app (it's very flexible to this sort of customization), and update an attribute that designates your app version.  You have a few options for updating the attribute.

### Environment Attributes

If you run the chef-client service, which runs chef periodically, you can just have your CI edit the chef environment using knife.  Each new release by CI would result in a call to the chef-server to update the environment to use the new version of your application.  The next chef-client run would pickup that version change, and update your app.

### Passing JSON

You can have your CI run chef-client directly on the required nodes, and pass in a node json file with the -j flag.  In this case, your CI will directly pass the new version in.

### Other attribute locations

Following the same pattern as Environment attributes, you could use knife to update the node or role attributes as well.  These are all merged together when chef-client runs, so any of them would work.